# incorrect output when using testcases else it's working fine(stacks used)

Tags: c++, stack, destructor, testcasesource

below i have uploaded a code to check if there parentheses in a string are balanced or not using stacks.It is working for 1 input,but for multiple testcases the correct output is not working.PLEASE HELP.THANKS IN ADVANCE.

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >>t;
    cin.ignore();
    while(t--)
    {
        {

            stack s;
            char *st;
            st=new char[100];
            gets(st);

            s.create(strlen(st));

            if(!count_elem(st))//counts if the brackets are in pairs or not
                cout << "NO" <<endl;
            else
            func1(s,st);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void func1(stack s,char *st)
{
    static int i=0,flag=0;
   // printf("%d %d\n",i,flag);
    if(st[i]=='(' || st[i]=='{' || st[i]=='[')
    {
        flag=1;
        s.push(st[i]);
    }
    else
        {
            if(s.isEmpty())
                flag=0;
            else
            {

                if(st[i]=='}')
                    {
                        //printf("%c\n",s.get_top());
                        if(s.get_top()=='{')
                        {
                            flag=1;
                            s.pop();

                        }
                        else
                            flag=0;

                     }

                if(st[i]==')')
                    {
                        //printf("%c\n",s.get_top());
                        if(s.get_top()=='(')
                        {
                            flag=1;
                            s.pop();

                        }
                        else
                            flag=0;

                    }

            if (st[i]==']')
                    {
                        //printf("%c\n",s.get_top());
                        if(s.get_top()=='[')
                        {
                            flag=1;
                            s.pop();

                        }
                        else
                            flag=0;

                    }
            }
        }
    i++;
    if(flag==1)
    {
        if(i<strlen(st))
        func1(s,st);
        else
            cout << "YES"<<endl;
    }

        else
        cout << "NO"<< endl;



}
```

Comment: For what test case does it fail?

Comment: the first testcase is always correct but it just shows some randomn output for all the other testcases that follow.

Comment: The first one, eh? I wasn't asking you *how many* tests it fails, I wasn't asking you *in what order* you run the passing and failing tests, I was asking for a failing test case. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is...when the program goes from one testcase to another,it does not reinitialize i=0,flag=0...because they have been declared as static variables.What can be done instead is....declare i,flag globally....and assign i=0;flag=0; just before making the first func()call for every testcase....

```
    int main()

{
    int t;
    cin >>t;
    cin.ignore();
    while(t--)
    {
        {

            stack s;
            char *st;
            st=new char[100];
            gets(st);

            s.create(strlen(st));

            if(!count_elem(st))
                cout << "NO" <<endl;
            else
            {
              i=0;
              flag=0;
              func1(s,st);

            }


        delete []st;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```